# Exposing Docker Remote API v1.22 on CentOS7

Tags: linux, docker, installation, centos7

I am trying to expose docker remote API on CentOS7.

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.10.3
 API version:     1.22
 Package version: docker-common-1.10.3-46.el7.centos.14.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.6.3
 Git commit:      cb079f6-unsupported
 Built:           Fri Sep 16 13:24:25 2016
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:         1.10.3
 API version:     1.22
 Package version: docker-common-1.10.3-46.el7.centos.14.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.6.3
 Git commit:      cb079f6-unsupported
 Built:           Fri Sep 16 1
```

I have conf file set up on `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-external.conf`

```
 [Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

followed by

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl docker restart
```

This doesn't seem to start any docker process on 4243

Comment: directly add -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 to your /lib/systemd/system/docker.service  then 
systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: That worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding add -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 to your `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file then running `systemctl daemon-reload`, followed by `systemctl restart docker` helps expose the remote API.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-current daemon \
--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd \
-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix://var/run/docker.sock \
```

Comment: A systemd drop-in as I've explained over here would be a more elegant solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45545785/414075