# Docker - Enable Remote HTTP API with SystemD and "daemon.json"

Tags: json, ubuntu, docker, systemd, docker-api

### Disclaimer:

On a old machine with Ubuntu 14.04 with Upstart as init system I have enabled the HTTP API by defining `DOCKER_OPTS` on `/etc/default/docker`. It works.

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 (...)

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 (...)
```

---

### Problem:

This does solution does not work on a recent machine with Ubuntu 16.04 with SystemD.

As stated on the top of the recent file installed `/etc/default/docker`:

```
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

#
# THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD
#
#   Please see the documentation for "systemd drop-ins":
#   https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/
#
(...)
```

As I checked this information on the [Docker documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/) for SystemD I need to fill a `daemon.json` file but as stated on the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd//#daemon-configuration-file) there are some properties self-explanatory but others could be under-explained.

That being said, I'm looking for help to convert this:

`DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -G myuser --debug"`

to the `daemon.json`object?

---

### Notes

**PS1:** I'm aware that the `daemon.json` have a `debug: true` as default.

**PS2:** Probably the `group: "myuser"` it will work like this or with an array of strings.

**PS3:** My main concern is to use SOCK and HTTP simultaneous.

---

**EDIT (8/08/2017)**
After reading the accepted answer, check the @white_gecko answer for more input on the matter.

Comment: Please note if you follow any of the steps here you will create an unencrypted remote root login to the server without any password or credentials. It is trivial for anyone with network access to your host to run a container as root with the host filesystem mounted. Securing this socket is strongly advised: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a lot of fragmented documentation it was difficult to solve this.

My first solution was to create the `daemon.json` with

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://127.0.0.1:2376"
  ]
}
```

This does not worked this error `docker[5586]: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json` after tried to restart the daemon with `service docker restart`.
Note: There was more on the error that I failed to copy.

But what this error meant it at the start the daemon it a conflict with a flag and configurations on `daemon.json`.

When I looked into it with `service docker status` this it was the parent process: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://`.

What it was strange because is different with configurations on `/etc/init.d/docker` which I thought that were the service configurations.
The strange part it was that the file on `init.d` does contain any reference to `daemon` argument neither `-H fd://`.

After some research and a lot of searches of the system directories, I find out these directory (with help on the discussion on this issue [docker github issue #22339](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22339)).

### Solution

Edited the `ExecStart` from `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` with this new value:
`/usr/bin/docker daemon`

And created the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "fd://",
    "tcp://127.0.0.1:2376"
  ]
}
```

Finally restarted the service with `service docker start` and now I get the "green light" on `service docker status`.

Tested the new configurations with:

```
$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
(...)
```

And,

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.23/info
[JSON]
```

I hope that this will help someone with a similar problem as mine! :)

Comment: Maybe the error message which you forgot to copy was: `unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: hosts: (from flag: [fd://], from file: [tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 fd://])`

Comment: You don't need to change original `docker.service`, you can use systemd drop-in file, such as: `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/no_fd.conf` with `[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and actually in my eyes the easiest solution which should doesn't touch any existing files, which are managed by the system update process is, to use a systemd drop-in:
Just create a file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` which overwrites the specific part of the service in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`.

In this case the content of `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` would be:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --tlsverify --tlscacert=/etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/etc/docker/server-cert.pem --tlskey=/etc/docker/server-key.pem -H=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H=fd://
```

(You could even create a directory `docker.service.d` which contains multiple files to overwrite different parameters.)

After adding the file you just run:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Your suggestion it is a good one! I'm gonna edit the question to new viewers check your answer as well.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Debian stretch; I get `docker.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.`

Comment: Note that IP should be `0.0.0.0` if you want to achieve accessibility from the outside, otherwise it will be available only via localhost. Also, Docker docs suggest using `2376` port for TLS connections instead of `2375`.

Answer (score 5):

The solution described at https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/#troubleshoot-conflicts-between-the-daemonjson-and-startup-scripts works for me:

> One notable example of a configuration conflict that is difficult to
>   troubleshoot is when you want to specify a different daemon address
>   from the default. Docker listens on a socket by default. On Debian and
>   Ubuntu systems using `systemd`), this means that a `-H` flag is always
>   used when starting `dockerd`. If you specify a hosts entry in the
>   `daemon.json`, this causes a configuration conflict (as in the above
>   message) and Docker fails to start.
>
> To work around this problem, create a new file
>   `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` with the following
>   contents, to remove the `-H` argument that is used when starting the
>   daemon by default.
>
> ```
> [Service]
> ExecStart=
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
> ```

Note that the line with `ExecStart=` is actually required, otherwise it'll fail with the error:

> docker.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.

After creating the file you must run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 2):

For me worked on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and Docker 18.06.0-ce create 
*/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/remote-api.conf*
with following content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

then run *sudo systemctl daemon-reload* and *sudo systemctl restart docker*
See result calling:

*curl http://localhost:2376/info*

You might need to configure proxy, if your docker is behind a proxy. 
To achiev this paste in /etc/default/docker file following:

```
http_proxy="http://85.22.53.71:8080/"
https_proxy="http://85.22.53.71:8080/"
HTTP_PROXY="http://85.22.53.71:8080/"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://85.22.53.71:8080/"
# below you can list some *.enterprise_domain.com as well
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"
```

Or Create 
*/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/remote-api.conf* with following content:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://<you_proxy_ip>:<port>"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://<you_proxy_ip>:<port>/"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"
```

I hope it helps someone...